# Use cmd prompt findstr to output only certain set of characters in string

Tags: windows, cmd

Using the cmd prompt, I am trying to use the **findstr** feature to output certain criteria from a txt file. 
My txt file contains a list of .exe names, including comments. There are alot of them- I want to parse out only the "name.exe" of each line. 
Here are examples of different lines in the txt file

```
C:\\Programme\\Windows Media Player\\mplayer2.exe""=dword:00000000
HOPSTER.EXE; Hopster
```

Out of these, I want only "mplayer2.exe" and "hopster.exe" to be included in the print out. 
Instead, I receive this:

**script**: `findstr "*.exe" Exies.txt`

output:

```
.\Exies.txt:""C:\\Programme\\Windows Media Player\\mplayer2.exe""=dword:00000000

.\Exies.txt:HOPSTER.EXE; Hopster
```

I was able to pull out some items using this script, findstr `/e ".exe"` Exies.txt, 
but am having trouble with the other examples above.

Any help? Please and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it only with findstr (I'm not aware of any FINDSTR output format that would let you print only the matched patterns).

Instead, you could use select-string from PowerShell:

```
C:\>powershell
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\> select-string -Path Exies.txt -Pattern "([a-z0-9]+)\.exe" -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }
mplayer2.exe
HOPSTER.EXE

PS C:\>
```

Comment: Hey thanks, this did pull out a good chunk of the results, but not quite all of them. I'm trying to determine which ones didn't show up in the output....

Comment: Sure. Most probably you need to adjust the regex - ([a-z0-9]+)\.exe

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure batch solution (there are many explanatory `rem`-arks in the code, so don't be shocked about the extent).
The most tricky parts are to get the offset position beyond the ".exe" extension for proper truncation of the string read from each line of `Exies.txt`, and to determine the start position of the file name:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem regular expression for `findstr` which means:
rem a string consisting of a sub-string with at least one character,
rem NOT containing any of '\?*/:<>"', followed by ".exe";
rem such strings are considered as valid executable file names
set REGEX="[^\\?\*/:<>|\""]*[^\\?\*/:<>|\""]\.exe"
rem parse the output of `findstr` with a `for /F` loop
rem (note that `findstr` is told to do case-insensitive searches)
for /F "tokens=*" %%F in ('findstr /I /R %REGEX% Exies.txt 2^> nul') do (
  rem assign a single matching line to variable `LINE`
  set "LINE=%%F"
  rem call sub-routine to retrieve length of string portion after the
  rem (first) occurrence of ".exe"; the length is also equal to the
  rem character offset of the string portion after the ".exe" occurrence
  call :STRLEN "!LINE:*.exe=!" LEN > nul
  rem use another `for` loop to truncate `LINE` after ".exe";
  rem so afterwards we have everything up to the ".exe" portion
  for %%A in (!LEN!) do (
    set "LINE=!LINE:~,-%%A!"
  ) & rem next %%A
  rem replace double-quotes '"' and colons ':' by backslashes '\'
  set "LINE=!LINE:"=\!
  set "LINE=!LINE::=\!"
  rem wrap around another `for` loop to extract the file name portion
  rem (this is done to remove any paths from the "*.exe" file name)
  for %%B in ("!LINE!") do (
     set "LINE=%%~nxB"
  ) & rem next %%B
  rem safety check if extracted "*.exe" file name still matches the
  rem regular expression (necessary if ".exe" occurs twice in a line)
  echo !LINE! | findstr /I /R %REGEX% > nul 2>&1
  if not ErrorLevel 1 (
    rem output final "*.exe" file name
    echo !LINE!
  ) & rem end if
) & rem next %%F
endlocal
exit /B

:STRLEN
rem this constitutes a sub-routine to get the length of a string
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "STR=%~1"
if "%STR%" EQU "" (
  set /A LEN=0
) else (
  set /A LEN=1
  for %%I in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
    if not "!STR:~%%I!" EQU "" (
      set /A LEN+=%%I
      set "STR=!STR:~%%I!"
    ) & rem end if
  ) & rem next %%I
) & rem end if
endlocal & set /A LEN=%LEN%
if not "%~2" EQU "" set %~2=%LEN%
echo %LEN%
exit /B
```

**Assumptions:**

- the ".exe" portion occurs once per line of `Exies.txt` only;
- the file name consists of at least one character other than these `\?*/:<>|"`;
- the file name is delimited to the left by

  - either a backslash `\` or a colon `:` (meaning that a path has been specified),
  - or a double-quote `"` (it might have been enclosed in a pair of such);

Comment: wow, not sure where to even begin with this... I'm a beginner, so I will try to muddle through some of this. Thanks.

Comment: there are lots of `rem` remarks which quide you through the code; let me know if something is unclear...